# Bit Counting (just the #1)

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement

I made a function that follows this Example: The binary representation of 1234 is 10011010010, so the function should return 5 in this case.

But after testing it do give me the default variable value.

My code:

```
public class BitCounting {

    public static int countBits(int n){
        int r;
      String bits = Integer.toBinaryString(n);
      if (n < 0){
        r = 0;
        }else{
      int count = bits.length();
      for (int i=0; i == count ;i++){
        int c = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(bits.charAt(i)));
        if ( c==1){ 
          r =+ 1;
          };
        };
      };
    return r;
  }
    
}
```

I believe that for some reason it is not reading the `If` statement as well as the `for` statement

Comment: start working on correct/consistent indentation of the code - as posted here it is VERY hard to read/understand/debug || BTW you can compare characters `charAt(i) == '1'` || BTW2 since you are already using `Integer`, it has a `bitCount()` method

Comment: VTC as typo. `r =+ 1;` should be `r++;` **or** `r += 1;` also `i == count` should be `i < count` in the loop condition. Converting the `int` to a binary string is a bit wasteful, `int r = 0; for (; n > 0; n /= 2) { if ((n & 1) == 1) { r++; } } return r;`

Comment: How did this code print anything?  It is syntactically flawed and would not compile.  You did not initialize `r` to `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not incrementing `r` correctly.  Use `r++;`  And some ide's may complain about not explicitly initializing `r`.

But you don't need to convert to a string. Assuming you don't want to or can't use `Integer.bitCount()`, then here is one way.

- initialize count to 0.
- check the least significant bit (LSB). If `n&1` return `0` if LSB is `0`, else it returns `1`.
- `n>>1` shifts right 1 bit to expose next bit.

```
public static int countBits(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
       count += n&1;
       n >>= 1;
    }
   return count;
}
```

Comment: "some ide's may complain" - I think every Java compliant compiler must complain about not explicitly initializing `r` (a local variable). JLS [Chapter 16. Definite Assignment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-16.html): "Every local variable declared by a statement (§14.4.2, §14.14.1, §14.14.2, §14.20.3) and every blank final field (§4.12.4, §8.3.1.2) must have a definitely assigned value when any access of its value occurs."

Comment: @user16320675 I wasn't certain.  Eclipse complains.  But the OP says his code prints the default value even though `r` has not been initialized.  My assumption was that if it was required, his code wouldn't compile.

Comment: good point... how did they run it?

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about the LSB or the n>>1. Great and concrete explanation.

Comment: @JuanDiegoPenaCastillo  Using `&` is an AND operation.  It is useful for masking off bits.   I recommend you read up on AND, OR `|`and XOR (exclusive OR) (in java it's `^`) to see how they work.  They can be a great help in some programming algorithms. Check out [Bit Operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)